# Accessing data from API and outputting in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I have an API (`/js/feed/sms.json`) that returns data that looks like this:

```js
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Test feeds 1",
        headline: "Here is a headline",
        feed-url: "/something?q=1"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Test feeds 2",
        headline: "Here is another headline",
        feed-url: "/something?q=2"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Test feeds 3",
        headline: "Here is a third headline",
        feed-url: "/something?q=3"
    }
]
```

I have a couple of React components.

The first is a call to an API:
fetch-api-data.jsx:

```js
import * as axios from 'axios';

export default class FetchApiData {
  constructor() {
    console.log('FetchAPIData loaded');
  }
  static shareMyStoryData(URL) {
    return axios.get(URL)
    .then(function (response) {
      
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

The second is a component that parses the data.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as DOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';
import './share-my-story.scss';
import FetchApiData from './fetch-api-data';

class ShareMyStory extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      smsData: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const URL = '/js/feed/sms.json';
    FetchApiData
      .shareMyStoryData(URL)
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({smsData: response });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
console.log(this.state.smsData);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.smsData.name}<h1>
        <h2>{this.state.smsData.headline}</h2>
        <h3><a href={this.state.smsData.link}>{this.state.smsData.link}</a></h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ShareMyStory.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  headline: PropTypes.string,
  link: PropTypes.string,
  smsData: PropTypes.array
}

DOM.render(
  <ShareMyStory/>, document.getElementById('share-my-story'));
```

I'm having 2 problems:

First is that I'm getting undefined in my console.log of the `this.state.smsData`.

Second, I need to loop thru that object and output the items in the return. I'm coming from Angular, so I'm familiar with their iterative `ng-repeat`, but I don't see a similar tool in React. Is there a preferred way to do this?

Comment: Do you get any data after performing the get?

Comment: If I log in the `shareMyStoryData` method in `fetchDataApi` class, I see the data from the `get`. In the console.log statement in the return in the ShareMyStory.jsx component, I get `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have that empty `.then(function(response){})` in your FetchApiData, then that is the problem. Either add { return response } there (useless, but at least then it should work) OR remove that `.then`.

For your second question, as pointed out by others: In React you use the `.map` method of an array to iterate an array:

```
{ this.state.smsData.map(data => <div>...</div>) }
```

Some points: if your smsData is (or will be) an array, then it's better to initialise it with either `undefined` or an empty array. I would advise `undefined`, so you can make the distinction between A) there is no data yet, and B. The data has been fetched, but there are no records *(i.e. `smsData.length === 0`)*

In your component you can then check whether to render the data, a loading indicator, or some message that there are no records, something like:

```
render() {
    const { smsData } = this.state;
    if (!smsData) { return <div>Loading...</div>; }
    if (smsData) {
        if (smsData.length === 0) { return <div>No data</div>; }
        return smsData.map(data => <div>...</div>);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems the issue was two fold: 1) Having the .then in the `FetchApiData` method was indeed the cause. Moving that to where the method is used in the component solved it. There was also the case of the JSON not being properly formed (missing the double quotes around the key names). Addressing both of those issues solved the problem. Thanks to all for the assistance!

Comment: Glad you solved it. By the way, if you dont really make a call to an external API, but read from a local file, you dont need axios at all :)

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. In this case, the feed is on a local file for dev purposes, but will be an external API URL once the feed is ready.

Comment: I figured as much. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

1) Check which one is logging first, maybe your fetchData isn't completed when you're render() is fired. That's why you're getting the default smsData.

2) In order to loop through data, assuming dataArray is the array you need to loop through

```
FetchApiData
  .shareMyStoryData(URL)
  .then((response) => {
    // See if this is logging after Render is logged in
    console.log('In FetchApiData: ', this.state.smsData);
    this.setState({smsData: response });
  })

render() {
  console.log('In Render: ', this.state.smsData);

  const listItems = this.state.dataArray.map(function(item) {
    return (
      <li key="{item.name}">
        <a href="{item.link}">{item.name}</a>
      </li>
    );
  });
  return (<ul>{listItems}</ul>);
}
```

Comment: this.setState(...) should call forceUpdate() which will rerender the component. Shouldnt state.smsData then be filled with the correct data?

Comment: Logging in both areas yields `undefined`, but if I log the response in the `fetch-data-api.tsx` file (in the .then function), I get the data.

Comment: Fixed the issue of the data not returning, but when I try to implement the .map for the return, I get this error: `TypeError: smsData.map is not a function`
I'm setting smsData right inside render() with: `const { smsData } = this.state;`  as shown above in 0Rxm's answer.

Comment: Is `smsData` an array? map() is an default prototypal function of arrays

Comment: `smsData` is an array of objects. See the structure at the top of the question.

Comment: Hahaha, silly of me. Problem is in your smsData. Property name of an object cannot have '-' in it. As objects of your `smsData` array has a property named `feed-url`. It is getting undefined hence smsData isn't having a map method as its not an array. So try changing `feed-url` to `feed_url` or `feedUrl` and code accordingly

Comment: @TWLATL, has this fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the data and the state is changing but when you console.log it returns undefined it might be because the setState function is not done by the time you call console.log.

Try something like this, The function will execute after the setState portion is done.

```
this.setState({
            someSate: obj
        }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.smsData);
        });
```